# c++ console closing after cin.get is placed

Tags: c++, cin

i am writing a basic program to convert meters to feet

```
// TestApp.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
# include <iostream>


int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    double feet;
    short int input;
    const double feettometer = 3.28 ; (changed after second comment, small mistake)

    cout << "Enter meter value: ";
    cin >> input;

    feet = feettometer * input ;

    cout << "your meter value of " << input << " in feet is " << feet ;
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

why does this con.get() not keep the console alive?

Comment: Maybe because of the newline at the end of the input.

Comment: const int feettometer = 3.28 ; Why not double?

Comment: sorry, changed to double, small little mistake but problem persists

Comment: You can probably configure your IDE to keep the terminal window open for you. That way you don't have to add unrelated code to your programs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you type in a number like `123` and hit enter, the input stream has `123\n` in it. When you extract into `input`, `123` is removed and `\n` is left in the stream. Then when you call `cin.get()`, this `\n` is extracted. It doesn't need to wait for any input because this character is already there waiting to be extracted.

So one solution is to clear the input stream with `ignore` before doing `get`:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

This will extract and discard anything up to and including the next `\n` in the stream. So if your input was `123hello\n`, it would even discard the `hello`.

An alternative would be to read the input line using `std::getline` (which will extract the `\n` too) and *then* parse the line for the input number.

Comment: im just curios, thanks for the response, but isnt there a shorter way, I know than in c# all you need is console.readline(), is ther not another way of byassing the "/n" in the input stream?

Comment: @user2699451 `std::getline()` should work here as well.

Comment: @Angew Getline does not work, it underline the period with error (Error 1 error C2661: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::getline' : no overloaded function takes 0 arguments c:\users\charles\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\testapp\testapp\testapp.cpp 24 1 TestApp
)

Comment: @user2699451 Yeah, you would have to give it a dummy `std::string` for it to read into. That's why I think `cin.ignore` better expresses intent.

Comment: @user2699451 You're referring to the `getline()` meber function, not to the function `std::getline()`. But you're right it would need a dummy `std::string`.

Answer (score -1):

because, it reads last character, write it twice, bad solution so:

> cin.get();
>
> cin.get();

or Just try

> System("pause");

which will free your screen